# Read a file line by line from last

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a requirement to read the file line by line from last line until the first line. Right now I am able to read the file line by line from start with the below piece of code.

```
while IFS= read line
do
  #Logic here
done <"$Input_File"
```

Kindly help me out with a solution to read the file line by line from last line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tac` to read the file from the last line until the first. Using your example you could do:

```
while IFS= read line
do
  #Logic here
done <<<(tac "$Input_File")
```

See the manual page for [tac](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/tac.1.html) *(this may not be installed by default in your distribution but should be available using the package manager).*

Comment: tac is not available in my flavor of UNIX. any other option that you can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
file="path/to/your/file.txt"
awk '{print NR ":" $0}' $file | sort -t: -k 1nr,1 | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*://'
```